# VITEST VUE SCRIPT SETUP: How to test if a method is called inside onMounted

Tags: vue.js, vitest, spyon

How can you test if a method is called inside the onmount in vue with script setup.
The problem is that there is documentation that is done with option api where in the test I can call the component and access its methods, with script setup it is not like that, I must use expose, when I use expose I can access the method that I want to spy on, but I cannot verify if it is called or not.
In order to spy on the method, I must access the wrapper.vm and the wrapper is accessible only after mounting the component. When I want to spy on the onmount, the component is already mounted and does not detect the method call

In order to spy on the method, I must access the wrapper.vm and the wrapper is accessible only after mounting the component. When I want to spy on the onmount, the component is already mounted and does not detect the method call

Component

```
<script setup>
  import { onMounted } from 'vue';

  const methodTest = async () => {
     await .......
  }

  onMounted(()=>{
    methodTest();
  })

  defineExpose({ methodTest })
</script>
<template>
  <div>Component</div>
</template>
```

How to test if methodTest is called inside onMounted, testing with vitest in vue 3

Comment: You cannot. Test the component as a single unit.

Comment: in api option if possible

Comment: Normally, you would not test certain functions in your component. Is better to test if the output is correct. If you need to test functionality, you could create a composable that you can test

Comment: I understand, but that is not the question I am asking, I am following a guide to learn this type of case, if it is convenient to carry out this type of test or not, it is a different topic, what I respectfully asked is if anyone knew how to do it, because I saw that in the API options if possible, they import the component and can access all its methods before mounting them, in composition I must go through the VM first and the VM is available after mounting the component and when I mount the component the onmount it goes off and I can't do the spy